# saving/recalling VBA variables in Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA in Word 2013 to score and return some basic info that the end user will input in the document in some legacy form fields.  My code, which works fine if I have it all in a single sub, is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScoreLevel()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim Score as Integer
Dim Level as String

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text37").Result < "33" Then
    a = 2
Else
    a = 0
End If

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text40").Result = "0" Then
    b = 0
ElseIf ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text40").Result = "1" Then
    b = 1
ElseIf ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text40").Result > "1" Then
    b = 2
Else
    b = 0
End If

Score = a + b

Select Case Score
    Case 0 To 1
        Level = "Low"
    Case 2 To 3
        Level = "Moderate"
    Case Is > 3
        Level = "High"
End Select

MsgBox "Score = " & Score & vbNewLine & "Level: " & Level 

End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to separate the a variable and the b variable routines into their own (individual) sub routines, but the variables did not pass down.  Any help how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, either you declare the separate subroutines e.g.
    sub mySub(myVar as integer)
then call the sub within your code with:
    mySub(b)
The 2nd way is to declare the variables outside any subroutines like:
    public b as integer
then you can simply use them in all subroutines.

Comment: Thanks... I like the latter option much better and it works great! It's a little cleaner and I don't have to edit my existing code. Are there any disadvantages to using it over the first option?

Comment: In smaller solution not really, but if you plan to extend it it can get messy with e.g. 10 public vars with god knows where assignments